# Trying to remove an element from an array i get this error: Contextual type 'Int' cannot be used with array literal

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, swift4

I added a button for the reloadCell in a tableView and i would like, when the button is pressed,  to remove the element of an array on the specific cell but i'm getting this error

> Contextual type 'Int' cannot be used with array literal

```
@IBAction func reloadCell(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let index = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
        sortedArray.remove(at: [index])    //HERE I GET THE ERROR
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [index], with: .right)
    }
```

How can i solve it?

Comment: sortedArray.remove(at: sender.tag)

Comment: You need integer instead of IndexPath class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays use `Int`s as indices, not `IndexPath`s as `tableView` does:

```
sortedArray.remove(at: sender.tag)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't use an IndexPath type for array (you should use int type)
for ex:

```
        sortedArray.remove(at: index.row) 
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: index.row, with: .right)
```